# JSON schema containing conditional logic

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, data-modeling

I am creating a json schema for a web application. The schema contains among others some `compute_parameters` that will be specified by the user like setting `include_direct_transport` to true or false, and also contains input data coming from database, for simplicity let's call those `dataset1` and `dataset2`. Now I also have `dataset3` and `dataset4` that I also want to include as an input data to my application but only when the `include_direct_transport` is set to true. What will be the best approach to do it? I want to avoid redundancy and preferably would like to have everything defined in one file, but how can I handle the condition here? Is there a way to define in json: if `include_direct_transport` == True then include `dataset3` and `dataset4` as well and validate them? Below a small example of my schema

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "metadata": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "run_id": {"type": "string", "format": "uuid"},
      ...
    },
    "required": ["run_id"...]
  },
  "compute_parameters": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "include_direct_transport": {"type": "boolean"}
    ...
    },
    "required": ["include_direct_transport" ...]
  },
  "input_data": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "dataset1": {
        "type": "array"
         ...}
      "dataset2": {
        "type": "array"
         ...}
```

And this is how I handle it right now but since I never before had to define json schema I am not sure what would be the best approach here. I guess I am looking for some general suggestions and best practices. thanks in advance

```
"dependencies": {
  "compute_parameters": {
    "properties": {
      "include_direct_transport": {
        "enum": [true]
      }
    },
    "required": ["dataset3", "dataset4"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dependencies` keyword is not quite what you want in this case. In order to define a conditional against the *value* of a property (rather than the *presence* of a property) you need the `if`/`then` keywords.

`if` and `then` are normal schemas. If the `if` schema passes validation against the instance, then the `then` schema must pass validation as well. So, `if` defines a schema where the value of `/compute_parameters/include_direct_transport` is `true`, and `then` asserts that `/input_data/dataset3` and `/input_data/dataset4` are present.

```json
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "compute_parameters": {
        "properties": {
          "include_direct_transport": { "const": true }
        },
        "required": ["include_direct_transport"]
      }
    },
    "required": ["include_direct_transport"]
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "input_data": { "required": ["dataset3", "dataset4"] }
    },
    "required": ["input_data"]
  }
```

The solution is a bit verbose, but this is the best way to do it in my opinion. You can find more information about these keywords at https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#if-then-else